# iOS - Play multiple notes loaded from soundfount with a specific duration and possibility to stop individual

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

i'm currently working a musician app. In my app notes should be played with a specific duration. I don't get into detail when the notes are played. Basically there is a ui view (a vertical line) which is moving and when this hits my other ui views (rectangle) it should be played a note. Important here: the note should be played until the line is not hitting the rectangle anymore.

The note playing is no problem but I don't find any duration. Also it should be possible to play the same note multiple times with a delay.

So I tried to make this work with AudioKit cause it's seems like the best greatest solution for audio. But it has so much stuff. I took a look into their examples and found this:

```
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
    let soundPath = ("\(bundlePath)/sounds")

    let akSampler = AKAppleSampler()
    let mixer = AKMixer(akSampler)
    try! akSampler.loadSoundFont(soundPath, preset: 0, bank: 0)

    mixer.start()
    AudioKit.output = mixer
    do {
        _ = try AudioKit.engine.start()
    } catch {
        print("AudioKit wouldn't start!")
    }

    do {
       try akSampler.play(noteNumber: myNote.rawValue, velocity: 100, channel: 1)
    } catch let e{
        print(e)
    }
```

Unfortunately I can't pass any duration and when I call `akSampler.stop(noteNumber: myNote.rawValue)` it also stops the other notes with the same type.

I tried to find a solution with AVFoundation like so:

```
    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()
    engine.attach(sampler)
    engine.connect(sampler, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

    guard let bankURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sounds", withExtension: "SF2") else {
        print("could not load sound font")
        return
    }
    
    ... init engine 

sampler.startNote(60, withVelocity: 64, onChannel: 0)
```

But same result. Also the same case that I can't pass any duration.

I also digged into MIDISequencer's but it seems that they generating a sequence which I can play but this does not fit on my problem.

Does someone has a solution here?

Comment: Hi, have you find a solution that you can share with me? I'm facing the same application as yours thanks

Answer (score 0):

The laziest solution would be to just schedule a stop with asyncAfter when you trigger the note, e.g.,

```
func makeNote(note: MIDINoteNumber, dur: Double) {
    sampler.play(noteNumber: note, velocity: 100, channel: 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + dur) {
            self.sampler.stop(noteNumber: note)
        }
}
```

A better solution would probably use either `AKSequencer` or `AKAppleSequencer`. Both allow you to create sequences on the fly by adding individual notes with a specified duration (in musical time, i.e., number of beats). `AKSequencer` is considerably more accurate, but `AKAppleSequencer` has more readily available code examples on the web.  A little confusingly, the current `AKAppleSequencer` used to also be called `AKSequencer`, but their interfaces are sufficiently different that a quick look at the docs for the two classes will tell you which you're looking at.

Your question is asking about how to schedule MIDI events which is precisely what these classes are designed to do.  You haven't really given a clear reason why generating a sequence doesn't fit your problem.

Comment: Hi @c_booth. Thanks for you answer. In your problem I have the problem that when I play the same note multiple times but with different duration I can't stop them individually. The reason why I can't use the AKSequencer neither AKAppleSequencer is a UI problem but maybe you're right and thats the solution. I plan to play a bit with both. 
Just one other question. How does soundfonts work with AKSequencer? A piano would be great to play. I think cause of that the first idea that come in my mind was the AKAppleSampler where I can load a soundfont. ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that MIDI instruments, real or virtual, will not let you have multiple instances of the same note played simultaneously.  You will need multiple MIDI instruments to do that.  One way would be to use a sequencer and play the different notes on different channels. Or use an array of samplers.  Either way, you'll need a clever way to control which voice get stopped when (tbh, this sounds like an odd feature).  You should know that you are able to trigger UI events from a sequencer using AKCallbackInstrument or AKMIDICallbackInstrument.

Comment: And yes, you can use soundfonts with a sequencer, check out the docs, there are examples. If you have problems, it is best to post a separate question